# Root View Controller Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm working along with the book Beginning iPhone 3 Development, and am running into some issues on the "Pickers" app. I'm using Xcode 4.2, and I set it up exactly like they have it set up in their source code. All the code is the same, and all the outlet connections are the same. But, when I run my version, it launches a black screen, and the debugger says "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch."

There version in the source code runs just fine, and mine looks identical to it, but for some reason mine just won't run. I've Googled this issue and people have a bunch of workarounds, but I feel like there is something really simple in IB that I'm not seeing.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the RootViewControllers XIB-file? And is it connected to the RootViewController Class (in designer)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, sorry I'm still pretty new at this. I created the tab bar in "iPhone Window"'s nib, and made the "rootController" connection between the Tab Bar Controller and the App Delegate, just like they did in the working version.

Comment: Edit: Ehm are you sure you selected the TabBar based app when you created the project? Hm.. But the error says that there isn't a root view controller.

Comment: Oh no I didn't select that, I selected the "Empty" option, that may be my issue. I'm going to try that out now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone 3 book is probably having you add the view of your view controller as a subview of the window, correct? Well, since iOS 4, `UIWindow` now has a `rootViewController` property and setting this property to your initial view controller is now the preferred way to get your first view controller on screen.

Basically replace something like this in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your application delegate...

`[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];`

with this...

`self.window.rootViewController = viewController;`

Quite a bit has changed since iPhone OS 3; beware as you proceed through the book.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Unfortunately, I did not find `[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];`  Instead my code looks like this:  '[window addSubview:rootController.view];'
    '[window makeKeyAndVisible];'

Comment: I used `viewController` as an example. This would apply to whatever your root view controller happens to be called.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks a lot for your help Mark. I'm going to try and figure out what my root view controller is and go from there, I'm still a noob at this but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.